# Multi selection of options in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, multi-select, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, chips

> I wanted to implement multi election options for my chatbot in dialogflow. For Example selecting multiple chips what to do

Im trying with chips and buttons i want multi selection of those chips which rich text should i use